# Invalid Syntax When Calling A Function

Tags: python

I'm doing a tic-tac-toe game and when I try to pass the user selection to see if their selection is a free tile I keep getting an "Invalid Syntax" Error. I've tried every type of white space problem I could have had. I'm not dealing with strings so I'm unaware of what is causing this. Here is my code:

```
def freespace( tile ):
    global GAME_BOARD

    if tile in GAME_BOARD:
        print('That tile has already been selected')
    else:
        break

def secondPlayer():
    # Ask user for tile selection
    p2TileSelection = int(input('Player 2 please select a number.')

    freespace(p2TileSelection)
```

Any help is appreciated, if more code is required I have a total of 141 lines currently and I'll happily post it. Right now, all I showed was the error in the two functions where I'm defining the freespace function and where I'm calling it from another function.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: In my else statement before I just had it return, thinking I wasn't returning anything I switched it to break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. missing `)`

```
p2TileSelection = int(input('Player 2 please select a number.'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed a closing brace here.

```
p2TileSelection = int(input('Player 2 please select a number.')
```

This could be the cause of the  error

First Edit it to this;

```
p2TileSelection = int(input('Player 2 please select a number.'))
```

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

`break` needs to be inside a loop.

Comment: Yeah, before it was 'return'. I just switched it back to that after seeing +itzmeontv 's answer.